# Geometry of object looks messy in rendered image and rendered view mode

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, geometry

The Geometry of my object looks smooth and normal in the solid view, wireframe view and in the material preview. But as soon as I render my scene or go into the rendered view mode, the geometry looks really messy. All modifiers are applied and I have tried to flip the normals but the issue remains. What could be causing this and how do I solve it?

[image: Smooth object in the material view]

[image: Messy object in rendered view]

[image: Smooth object in solid view]

[image: Smooth object in material preview]

[image: Messy object in rendered image]

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to find out without your *.blend-file.
Perhaps there is a weired node configuration with a displacement node connected.
Or the normals of your object don't all face the right direction.

But without a *.blend-file  -> reading the glas sphere.